# NGINX & WordPress installation issue with existing ruTorrent install

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a dedicated server running ruTorrent using arakasi72's ruTorrent installation script:

https://github.com/arakasi72/rtinst

I wanted to install a WordPress site on this same server, but I'm running into errors and I don't understand how to fix them.

I used this tutorial to install WordPress:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-wordpress-ubuntu-20-04-nginx-mariadb-php7-4-lemp

Following the instructions was pretty straightforward right up until it came time to do:

`sudo nginx -t`

at which point I got the following output:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.<domain_name.tld>" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "<domain_name.tld>" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.<domain_name.tld>" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "<domain_name.tld>" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I know *what* the problem is, the problem is, I don't really understand *how to solve* the problem. I know that I have multiple server blocks defined, one of which is in the file located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, which is based off of https://github.com/arakasi72/rtinst/blob/master/conf/nginxsite and looks like:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        #server_name <Domain Name>;
        root /var/www;
        
        index index.html index.php index.htm;
        
        error_page 403 = @denied;
        #Below enter IP address or block to allow, eg LAN and/or VPN blocks
        allow 10.0.0.0/8;
        allow 172.16.0.0/12;
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;

        location @denied {
               return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        
        location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /rutorrent {
               auth_basic "Restricted";
               auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
               include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php;
               include /etc/nginx/conf.d/cache;
        }

        #include /etc/nginx/sites-available/dload-loc;

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

And the other server block is causing problems I guess? The one from the LinuxBabe tutorial which looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  root /usr/share/nginx/example.com/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

   location ~ ^/wp-json/ {
     rewrite ^/wp-json/(.*?)$ /?rest_route=/$1 last;
   }

  location ~* /wp-sitemap.*\.xml {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  error_page 404 /404.html;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

  client_max_body_size 20M;

  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  }

  #enable gzip compression
  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_types application/json text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;
  gzip_proxied any;

  # A long browser cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
       access_log        off;
       log_not_found     off;
       expires           360d;
  }

  # disable access to hidden files
  location ~ /\.ht {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
  }

}
```

Because arakasi72's script uses the standarized Apache directory structure of `/var/www/` for storing all web-related stuff, I wanted to keep that convention, and in the LinuxBabe tutorial, anywhere `/usr/share/nginx/` is present, I've changed that to `/var/www/` for consistency's sake (although if this isn't necessary, I'm fine with using the NGINX recommend `/usr/share/nginx/` location).

The functionality I want is that when I type in "www.<domain_name>.tld" in my browser, I want to be able to get to "www.<domain_name>.tld/wp-admin/install.php" so I can finish my WordPress installation and then people can simply type "www.<my_domain_name>.tld" and it goes straight to the WordPress site.

Where am I going wrong, and what do I need to do?